# Web Audio API Gain node envelope generators

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Im trying to make an envelope generator for my oscillator using automation on the gainNode and I want to be able to trigger the envelope whenever an event happens ( in this case a button click ).

But it seems like its working only the first time I click.
http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/T9mV2/

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var osc = context.createOscillator();
var gain = context.createGainNode();
var now = context.currentTime;

osc.frequency.value = 100;
osc.type = "sine";
osc.connect(gain);
osc.noteOn(0);

gain.connect(context.destination);
gain.gain.value = 0;


var trigger = document.getElementById('play');

trigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
  gain.gain.setValueAtTime(gain.gain.value, now);
  gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime( 1.0, now + 2.0 );
  gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime ( 0.0, now + 4.0 );
});
```

Why is it like that? And what is the best way to create envelope generators that can be triggered by events?

Answer (score 2):

Just move the line retrieving context.currentTime inside the click event listener.

```
trigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var now = context.currentTime;
  ...
```

The currentTime property exposes audio clock and so is updated in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
But given that the oscillator is always on, there should be a way to reset the phase of the oscillator every time its being triggered ( Phase Bashing ).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var osc = context.createOscillator();
var gain = context.createGain();

osc.connect(gain);
gain.connect(context.destination);
osc.start(0);

gain.gain.value = 0;

var oscStart = function(){
var now = context.currentTime;
gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues( now );
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(gain.gain.value, now);
gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1 , now + 0.2);
};

var oscOff = function(){
var now = context.currentTime;
gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues( now );
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(gain.gain.value, now);
gain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0 , now + 0.2);


};

$('#button').hover(oscStart , oscOff);


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/JJqNU/